# Non-Schengen to Schengen layover in Helsinki: Is 2 hours 25 minutes sufficient?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, connecting-flights, hel

I am planning to book a Finnair flight from Delhi to Iceland. There will be 2 connections in between, one at Helsinki and other at Copenhagen.

I am wondering if need to pass through Immigration at Helsinki to catch connecting flight?

My layover time in Helsinki is 2 hour 25 minutes, so i am worried if i pass through immigration then i may miss my connecting flight. And if i miss due to extra time in Immigration then will airline help in getting next flight and provide accommodation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finland, Denmark and Iceland are all part of the Schengen area, so you will have to clear immigration in Helsinki. While for some reason FinnAir do not list a [minimum connection time](https://www.finnair.com/de/gb/information-services/at-the-airport/finnair-ticket-office-and-transfer-service-desks) for non-Schengen to Schengen flights, the worst MCT they do list is 75 minutes. Given you have more than twice that time in your connection, you should not experience any trouble in making your connection, assuming the inbound flight is reasonably punctual. Furthermore, I gather the standard non-Schengen to Schengen MCT for Helsinki is just 40 minutes, and you have over three and a half times that.

If you do miss your connection due to circumstances outside your control (e.g. a late inbound flight), you will be rerouted by the airline to your final destination (i.e. Iceland) and provided accommodation if necessary, provided that you book all your flights on a single ticket. This will be the case, for example, if you book your entire journey at the same time on Finnair's website.